# unexpected token error when using onclick

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

this is my code

```
  const products = productArray.map(product =>
`
<tr>
  <td>${product.id}</td>
  <td>${product.type}</td>
  <td>${product.price}</td>
  <td><button onclick="${() => console.log('hello world')}">Examine</button></td>
</tr>
`
  );
  return tableBody.innerHTML = products.join('');
```

I just don't get why I'm getting this unexpected token error, that points to the html. I'm pretty sure It's a very stupid but I just cannot get where it is.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't substitute a function in a template literal. It simply inserts the function's source code.

There's also little point to it in this case. You can simply put the function body in the `onclick` attribute.

```
  const products = productArray.map(product =>
`
<tr>
  <td>${product.id}</td>
  <td>${product.type}</td>
  <td>${product.price}</td>
  <td><button onclick="console.log('hello world')">Examine</button></td>
</tr>
`
  );
  return tableBody.innerHTML = products.join('');
```

Comment: ok so there no way I can add this function for instance:
function clickHere() {console.log('hi')}

Comment: You can define the function in a `<script>` block, and then use `onclick="clickHere()"`. That's the normal way to use Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend You to use clientside templating engine to avoid such problems. For example [mustachejs](https://mustache.github.io/).

But about fix (try this one):

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById('productsTable');

const productArray = [
  {id: 1, type: 'something', price: 100},
  {id: 2, type: 'samething', price: 120}
];
const products = productArray.map(product =>
`
<tr>
  <td>${product.id}</td>
  <td>${product.type}</td>
  <td>${product.price}</td>
  <td><button onclick="(() => {alert('${product.id} ${product.type}');})()">Examine</button></td>
</tr>
`
  );
tableBody.innerHTML = products.join('');
```

```html
<table id="productsTable">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used this solution, it's a pitty because the other was shorter:

```
const products = productArray.map(product => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const td1 = document.createElement('td');
    const td2 = document.createElement('td');
    const td3 = document.createElement('td');
    const td4 = document.createElement('button');

    td4.addEventListener('click', () =>
      processSearch(product.id)
    );

    td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product.id));
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product.type));
    td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product.price));
    td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Examine'));
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    return tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  });
```